# Android Fragments Bug Duplicating error

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-fragments, android-gridview

I have created on activity and inside that i have created 9 fragment file which swipes from left to right.

All the 9 fragments will interact with mysql database and populate the data. But i found some bug in all the fragments that when i swipe from left to right it will populate correctly but again when i swipe from right to left the population starts duplicating the data.

Consider it is populating the listview and there are 4 data populating means 4 list view in one fragment when i go right side and come to left hand side again the same 4 data populating will duplicate and there will be 8 data's found

I am using android-java code and there is mysql interaction is being done in all the fragments 
seperately can anyone help how to restrict the fragments such that when i swipe or come back left side from right hand side it must not duplicate

Comment: Can you post some code for the fragment?

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast ya i will post the whole code now